# LibreOffice skips side borders?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice writer allowes me to format paragraphs with a border like:

[image]

but when I export it to PDF, I see no side borders.

[image]

Is this a bug? Can it be fixed or worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side borders may be too thin and can't be visible, have you tried looking at the pixels and seeing, if you have no pixels showing up, then just put it into a little bit bigger value where it is visible, like 0.35

Comment: say a thing, less than a second later MORE old things to see

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I used a very thin border thickness (0.05) and when I set it to 0.5-1.0 it is again visible in the PDF.